# How to clear "Unexpected side effect"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

From the following code, I get the **"Unexpected side effect"** error. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```js
computed: {
    sortedlist() {
        return this.data.sort((a, b) => {
            let modifier = 1;
            if (this.currentSortDir === 'desc') {
                modifier = -1;
            }
            if (a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) {
                return -1 * modifier;
            }
            if (a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) {
                return 1 * modifier;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change to the component's data props from within the computed prop is considered a *side effect*. Since [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array items *in place*, the original array is modified in your computed prop, which is a side effect.

A workaround is to use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a copy to sort:

```js
return this.data.slice().sort(...)
```